# Sign and Verify .exe file with C#

Tags: c#, windows, security, certificate, signtool

I want to make sure that an .exe file has been signed by ourselves. I have generated a self signed certificate via the method here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-code-signing-certificate/

Then I use SignTool to actually sign the .exe, this seems to work good.

How can I on the other end (on e.g. customers machine) with C# Verify that the .exe was signed by us?

Comment: Can you explain your use case a little more specifically? If you literally mean "How can ***I*** verify that it was signed" the obvious answer is you can right click on the .exe and check the properties/digital signature tab. But I think you meant to ask something else...?

Comment: The SignTool you used to sing the executable has also commands to verify the digital signature of files. It includes the option to specify a root SubjectName to test against. Or you could call [WinVerifyTrust()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wintrust/nf-wintrust-winverifytrust) yourself -- Assuming you want to test a signed file using an external tool. Otherwise, you could use the Evidence class (`Evidence.GetAssemblyEvidence()`), but it seems a bit silly to test integrity from an assembly that may have been tampered with :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jimi for great answer. I think that is what we need. What info should I supply to SignTool though? For signing I supply a .pfx, for verification what should I supply? The verification will happen on client machine so I suppose the .pfx should not be there. I dont want to have anything in the cert store.

Comment: If you want to use SignTool without a public key (or you don't want to call `WinVerifyTrust()`), as mentioned, you can simply verify that the signature is valid and provide the root certificate's Subject name, e.g., `SignTool.exe verify /pa /r "My Root Subject Name" c:\SomeFolder\SomeFile.exe` (double quotes required if the Subject name contains spaces). SingTool's exit code is `0` if the verification succeeded

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jimi for your help. I guess I need to use the public key then? My program should verify that the .exe was signed by us and nobody else. If it was not signed by us our program should reject it. Checking the root subject I guess somebody can just sign with the same name? What we trying to achieve is simply to check on the other end that it was signed by us (our pfx) and nothing else. This is a self signed cert.

Comment: Well, if you need to compare the public key, then just do that. Use the `/p7` switch. Anyways, check the SignTool's documentation to find whether you can use other comparisons that don't require temporary storage of your key

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, could you provide an answer for this question with relevant code so I can mark the question as solved?